# IntelliJ Run Configuration: Load variable from .properties file before launch

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I have a .properties file that always contains the up-to-date IP address of the remote server where my application is running. So I wanna configure IntelliJ to read the IP from that file when I launch the remote debugging Run Configuration, instead of manually updating the Run Configuration every time the IP changes.

I tried creating an external tool that sets an environment variable like this:

```
export SUT_IP=$(cat /absolute/path/to/.properties | sed -rn 's/^SUT\.0\.IP=([0-9\.]*)/\1/p')
```

The extraction works well in a terminal window:

```
$ export SUT_IP=$(cat /absolute/path/to/.properties | sed -rn 's/^SUT\.0\.IP=([0-9\.]*)/\1/p')
$ echo $SUT_IP 
10.61.14.146
```

, but I get a `error=2, No such file or directory` if I add the external tool to "Before launch" in my remote debugging Run Configuration and run. In addition, I notice in the error message, the `\1` in my `sed` command was changed to `/1`.

Apparently I was trying on a wrong direction. What is a recommended/common way of reading a variable when launching a Run Configuration in IntelliJ?

Comment: Before launch will not help here since these would be 2 separate processes not inheriting the environment of each other. Related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137820.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the request. @CrazyCoder .