# is it possible to 'source' a script before launching \ debugging an application in pycharm \ intelij?

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, pycharm

The use case is that we need some environment variable available to the applications (python \ java)

These variables are created by bash script.
While the script is very simple, it does contain some logic (like handling defaults, checking some system settings, etc) - so it can't be simply replaced by static environment configuration

Is there a way in pycharm and \ or intelij to source a shell script before executing the main program?

Comment: You can set env variables in `run configurations`.

Comment: I know, there's also a plugin to read an 'env' file, but what I need is to read env created by a script (with logic)

Comment: You can also set a `custom run command` there (at least in pycharm). Have you tried sth like `source script && java Main`.

Comment: interesting - where do if find this?

Comment: Also under `edit run configurations`

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for pycharm, it's possible to use a script instead of a "real" python interpreter.

using a script that sets up environment and then launches the "real" python interpreter works great

something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
. env.sh
python "$@"
```

didn't find a way to do a similar thing with java

Comment: By replacing `. env.sh` to `source <whatever_source_file>` and `python "$@"` to `/bin/sh "$@"` you are enable to source any file for bash scripts too.

Comment: Where exactly can you put these 3 lines of shell script code?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Please [vote for the related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137820).

There was also a similar question [already asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45561379/104891).

Comment: note that this is a slightly different issue - reading a predefined properties file is allready supported as a plugin